# Loop Over Datetime range in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a django model Journey where i have a start_date and end_date like this

```
class Journey(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Start date'))
    end_end = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('End date'))
```

and have another model which have foreignKey to this model 
    DAY_OF_WEEK = (('MO', 'Monday'),
               ('TU', 'Tuesday'),
               ('WE', 'Wednesday'),
               ('TH', 'Thursday'),
               ('FR', 'Friday'),
               ('SA', 'Saturday'),
               ('SU', 'Sunday'),)

```
class Schedule(models.Model):

    day = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DAY_OF_WEEK)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, )
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, )
    journey = models.ForeignKey(Journey)
```

What i want to do is that i want to iterate over all the days from the start_date to end_date. If the date belongs to a day which is in Schedule model then i want to update that date in a dictionary along with the other fields of the model so that i can iterate it on template. for this i tried this

```
import datetime
from time import strftime
def get_schedule_days(self):
    days=Schedule.objects.filter(journey=self).values('day')

    days_list=[]
    for day in days:
        days_list.append(day['day'])
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    schedule_dict={}
    while d <= end_date:
        if d.strftime("%A").upper()[:2] in days_list:

            schedule_dict.update('date',d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
        print d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        d += delta
```

is it the right way to di is or there is a better way to iterate over a range of dates and find all the days when schedule is scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating schedules are a messy problem, so I advise that you don’t try to reinvent the wheel for repeating schedules and use RRULE: http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57

To use this, Journey would not include dates. The Schedules model would have complete datetimes for start and end, and then an RRULE that describes how they repeat until the end date.